# Phaser 3 extract key out from texture

Tags: javascript, key, phaser-framework

[image: Inspect Element Console]

```
const CButton = this.add.image(0, 0, 'C').setInteractive()
const OButton = this.add.image(0, 0, 'O').setInteractive()
```

[image: Frontend]

Is that possible to extract the **texture**'s key out so that i can use to match whether the button is matched with the string at Frontend display to User?

Update: Here is my full code

**Create function**

```
 startTime = new Date();
    var characters = 'CO';
    var position = [57, 63];

    var result = ""
    var chaactersLength = characters.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chaactersLength));
    };

    const CButton = this.add.image(0, 0, 'C').setInteractive({ cursor: 'url(cursor/hand.cur), pointer' });
    const OButton = this.add.image(0, 0, 'O').setInteractive({ cursor: 'url(cursor/hand.cur), pointer' });

    this.aGrid = new AlignGrid({ scene: this, rows: 11, cols: 11 });
    this.text = this.add.text(0, 0, "Test Count: " + loop, { font: "20px Arial", fill: 'black' });
    this.aGrid.placeAtIndex(0, this.text);
    this.text = this.add.text(0, 0, result, style);
    this.aGrid.placeAtIndex(position[Math.floor(Math.random() * position.length)], this.text);
    this.aGrid.placeAtIndex(102, CButton);
    this.aGrid.placeAtIndex(106, OButton);
    this.time.addEvent({
        callback: () => {
            loop++;
            CButton.on('pointerdown',() => this.scene.start("scene1") + end(), CButton)
            OButton.on('pointerdown',() => this.scene.start("scene1") + end(), OButton)
        }
    })
```

**end()**

```
endTime = new Date();
var timeDiff = endTime - startTime; //in ms
// strip the ms
timeDiff /= 1000;

// get seconds 
var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff);
console.log(seconds + " seconds");
```

THe string is generate from the **result** variable. It will generate **C** and **O** key randomly. I created 2 button to detect user press the button matched with the string generated. If i can the texture key out of the image the i can write an ifelse statement for it

Comment: Your question is not clear. from where do you want to extract the texture-key? With what do you want to match the key with ? From where does the "frontend" - string come from? when should the match occure?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the **key** of an **image**, in an event-handler for example, you can pass the specific ***button/image*** as the scope of the event function *(link to [the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.GameObject.html#on__anchor))*.

And than you can get the `key`, from the `texture` property.

**Here a small example:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

let text;

function create () {
    /* START -- JUST CODE FOR THE DEMO CREATING IMAGES */
    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 60, 30);
    graphics.generateTexture('redButton', 60, 30);
    
    graphics.fillStyle(0x0000ff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 60, 30);
    graphics.generateTexture('blueButton', 60, 30);
    /* END -- JUST CODE FOR THE DEMO CREATING IMAGES */
    
    text = this.add.text(10, 10, 'Click the Red or Blue Button');
        
    let redButton = this.add.image(10, 40, 'redButton')
      .setOrigin(0)
      .setInteractive();
      
    redButton.on('pointerdown', handleClick, redButton);
      
    let blueButton = this.add.image(10, 90, 'blueButton')
      .setOrigin(0)
      .setInteractive();
    blueButton.on('pointerdown', handleClick, blueButton);
}

function handleClick(){
    text.setText(`The Button with the Key: '${this.texture.key}' was pressed!`);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

**Update, *based on comments*:**

Seeing your code and comment there are some this to look out:

1. **(optional)** I would not put the button event binding into a `time` function (that runs multiple times), since it will create multipe event-Listener. This *should* be better:

   ```
   CButton.on('pointerdown',() => this.scene.start("scene1") + end(), CButton);
   OButton.on('pointerdown',() => this.scene.start("scene1") + end(), OButton);
   this.time.addEvent({
       callback: () => {
           loop++;
       }
   });
   ```
2. that said, the `scope` will not be passed to a **arrow/lambda function**:

   **Scope will not work**:
   In this **arrow** function: `this` refers to current `scene` not the passed `CButton`.

   ```
    CButton.on('pointerdown',() => /* ... this = scene */, CButton);
   ```

   **Scope will work**:
   In this function: `this` refers to current the passed `CButton`.

   ```
    CButton.on('pointerdown', function(){
        //... this = CButton
    }, CButton);
   ```

**Second Update**

Just minor cleanup of the code

```
CButton.on('pointerdown', handler, CButton);
OButton.on('pointerdown', handler, OButton);

function handler(){
    this.scene.scene.start("scene1");
    end(this.texture.key, result);
}
```

Comment: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')* receive this when use this **${this.texture.key}** in my line

Answer (score 0):

I define it in the event function

```
CButton.on('pointerdown', function(){
        this.scene.start("scene1");
        var value = "C";
        end(value, result)
},this)
OButton.on('pointerdown', function(){
        this.scene.start("scene1");
        var value = "O";
        end(value, result)
},this)
```

After that pass the value i want as a argument in the end function

```
function end(value, result) {
```

}

It worked but not sure it is the best solution to do that

Comment: An easy solution is a good solution, so I find it good. if you want to use just one generic function for both event-handlers _(is abit more complex)_, check the last update of my answer.